# What is the advantage of running RSpec as a Rake task

Tags: ruby, rspec

What is the advantage of running RSpec as a Rake task? 
I mean I can just type `rspec` to run my rspec test cases or add the following lines to my rakefile and typing `rake` to run them but what is the point of doing that ?

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) 

task :default  => :spec
```

Forgive me if this is a dumb question, I am learning ruby now and I did google it and search SO but I can't find a satisfying answer.

Comment: Provide an example.

Comment: It probably looks a lot like running RSpec as a Rake task...

Comment: @Зелёный see my updated question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it for the same reason that you would use Rake to run any other task: so that Rake can automatically figure out which tasks to run in which order, instead of you having to manually figure that out yourself over and over again.

Rake is a library, a framework, and an internal DSL for *Dependency-Oriented Programming* in Ruby. A better-known name for such a tool is *Build Tool* or *Build System* ("Rake" is an obvious play on "Ruby `make`"), but actually, it can be used for much more than just building software.

Dependency-Oriented Programming allows you to define tasks and the dependencies between those tasks in a declarative style. The tool then figures out which tasks to run and in which order to satisfy those dependencies. Depending on the tool, it can also figure out which tasks can be run in parallel.

So, by running RSpec via Rake, you can for example declare that your RSpec task depends on some other task. Imagine, for example, you are building a translation software which needs the latest version of a dictionary file. Then, you could declare that your RSpec task depends on the dictionary file, and Rake would make sure that the dictionary exists before running your tests.

The other way around, you can declare that some task depends on the RSpec task. You could, for example, declare that the task which builds your gem and releases it to the public depends on the RSpec task, that way, you would only ever release a gem if the tests pass.

Comment: This is the first time I heard of "Dependency-Oriented Programming". I will do some research further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is redefining command somehow, for example:

Given a file named "Rakefile" with:

```
begin
  require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.fail_on_error = false
  end

  task :default => :spec
rescue LoadError
  # no rspec available
end
```

And spec:

```
RSpec.describe "something" do
  it "does something" do
    fail #< - note!
  end
end
```

When you run `rake` the exit status should be 0 (instead of not zero because of `fail`)

[ref](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/command-line/rake-task)

Comment: Thanks for the link I will check it further.